# How to set keyboard shortcut for "switch user" in Xubuntu?

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, switch-user

I am trying to create a keyboard shortcut in Xubuntu (13.04), but I have no idea what to put for the command. What is the command for invoking switch user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked with the source code of the 'actions button' plugin built in to the xfce4-panel  and the switch user mechanism uses `gdmflexiserver`, while most of the other actions use parameters to `xfce4-session-logout`.

The source was fetched with `apt-get source xfce4-panel`; the information was in  `~/xfce4-panel-4.10.0/plugins/actions/actions.c:`

```
case ACTION_TYPE_SWITCH_USER:
      succeed = g_spawn_command_line_async ("gdmflexiserver", &error);
      break;
```

You will find the executable at `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/gdmflexiserver`, which is actually just a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Copyright (C) 2011 Canonical Ltd
# Author: Michael Terry <michael.terry@canonical.com>
# 
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
# the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software
# Foundation, version 3 of the License.
#
# See http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html for the full text of the license.

if [ -z "$XDG_SEAT_PATH" ]; then
      # something went wrong
      exit 1
fi

dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DisplayManager $XDG_SEAT_PATH org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.Seat.SwitchToGreeter
```

It isn't in `$PATH`, so if you use it in a script, you will need to specify the absolute path. I am not sure whether it takes any other switches, but will add some further information if so.

Useful commands for scripts can also be found in the manpage for `xfce4-session-logout`, although the switch user action is not mentioned there, as it uses a different utility called `gdmflexiserver`.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent reply. That worked great. Also, I'm new to Xfce (and been away from linux for years) so knowing where to look as you've described is extremely helpful. Huge thanks!