# How to bind "Switch User" in Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce

Could someone tell me, how to actually bind the "Switch User" to a global hotkey? (as for a temporary replacement of lock screen issue)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set keyboard shortcut for "switch user" in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288165/how-to-set-keyboard-shortcut-for-switch-user-in-xubuntu)

Comment: Possibly, but I'm a bit new to linux in general (not speaking of xfce), so I failed to understand that reply in terms of usage

Comment: Follow-up reason: Marking as duplicate, after which the newer answer below can be merged into the older post later.

Answer (score 3):

And the answer was:

```
dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```

So, to properly bind this sort of stuff, goto `Applications > Keyboard > Application shortcuts`, from which `Add+`, and type in the new command (don't forget to remove the old one).
[image: config]

---

Continuing on this topic, I recently found one addition - Suspand, which also trips on `xflock4` and gives a black screen. Although this is a rough solution, but `sudo apt remove light-locker` solved the case (and don't forget to remove it from `Start-up`.

Comment: Actually, both the feature and command can be found within the default application menu in Xubuntu 18.04. Right-click on Whisker Menu, then select Properties > Commands - Enable "Switch Users".

Comment: Thanks. I was more looking for a way to set a hotkey like WIN+L to lock the desktop (and since the regular one gives a black screen, the user switch screen was the target)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This answer would be far more useful if you would be so bold as to include the steps you used to bind the above command to a hot key. If you do so, ping me and I'll upvote.

Comment: Sure, not a problem.